# Django-endless-pagination: apply javascript to whole html after "show more"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django, django-endless-pagination

**views.py**

```
class PortfolioListView(AjaxListView):
    model = Portfolio
    context_object_name = "portfolios"
    template_name = "portfolios/portfolio_list.html"
    page_template = 'portfolios/portfolio_list_page.html'
```

**portfolio_list.html**

```
{% extends "skeleton/base.html" %}


{% load el_pagination_tags %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="test-class">
        hi-1
    </div>

    <section>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-10">
                    {% include page_template %}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

{% endblock %}

{% block custom_js %}
    <script src="{% static 'el-pagination/js/el-pagination.js' %}"></script>
    <script>$.endlessPaginate({});</script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".test-class").click(function(){
                alert("ji");
            });
        });
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

**portfolio_list_page.html**

```
<div>
    {% lazy_paginate portfolios %}
    <div class="test-class">
        hi-2
    </div>
    <div class="test-class">
        hi-3
    </div>
    {% show_more %}
</div>
```

When I load `portfolio_list.html` page and click `hi-1`, it shows alert.

But when I click `show more` and click `hi-2` or `hi-3`, it doesn't show alert.

I want to show alert even I clicked `hi-2` or `hi-3`.

How can I implement this?

p.s Actually, this is a kinda very simple code for showing clearly what I want to do.

What I eventually want to do is **to execute whole javascripts code(`e.g _owl_carousel(), _flexslider(), _popover(), _lightbox(), _mixitup(),, etc`)   after loading portfolio_list_page so that this whole javascript function also can be applied to newly loaded page**